# Sequelize query to count total based on foreign key from second table (3 tables)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables. courses, course_sections, and course_videos. courses has a one to many relationship with course_sections which has a one to many relationship with course_videos. I want to return everything from courses along with the count of how many course_videos belong to each course_section. I have these models and I'm trying to run this query, but I get an error that

**Unknown column 'course_sections.course_section_id' in 'where clause'**

Please Help!

```
const Course = sequelize.define('Course', 
    {
        course_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        course_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        available: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false,
        },
        thumbnail_url:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(500),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false
        },
        course_description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        course_type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'courses',
        updatedAt: false
    }
);


const Course_Section = sequelize.define('Course-Section', 
    {
        course_section_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        course_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false,
        },
        course_section_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false
        },
        course_section_description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(500),
            allowNull: false
        },
        course_section_index: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'course_sections',
        updatedAt: false
    }
);
Course.hasMany(Course_Section, { foreignKey: 'course_id', sourceKey: 'course_id'});

const Course_Video = sequelize.define("Course_Video", 
    {
        video_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        course_section_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        video_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        video_bucket_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        video_file_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        video_order_index: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        length_seconds: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        views: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        likes: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        dislikes: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'course_videos',
        updatedAt: false
    }
);
Course_Section.hasMany(Course_Video, { foreignKey: 'course_section_id', sourceKey: 'course_section_id'});

Course.findAll({
        include: {
          model: Course_Section,
          attributes: [],
          include: {
            model: Course_Video,
            attributes: []
          },
        },
        attributes: [
            [sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course_videos WHERE course_videos.course_section_id = course_sections.course_section_id)'), 'video_count']
        ],
        group: ['course.course_id']
});
```

I have tried a few other queries, but I think I'm close with this one. My database is MySQL